# PrimeFaces doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem in my NewFile.xhtml. I use **jsf2.2**.

When I put the library **primefaces-3.5.jar** into my web/lib folder and restart tomcat server, the web page does not work anymore. When I remove my PrimeFaces jar file every thing works without showing my PrimeFaces tags.

I put the external jar correctly, but I think there is something wrong:

my web.xml file

```
  <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
 <web-app>
<display-name>Sample JSF 2 Filter login app</display-name>

<!-- Login filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>somePackage.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- Set the login filter to secure all the pages in the /secured/* path of the   application  -->



<!-- Staring JSF -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- JSF URL mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

   <!-- By default go to secured welcome page -->
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>NewFile.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

my NewFile.xhtml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

     <h:head>
        </h:head>
       <h:body>
<h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

<h:form>
   <p:editor value="#{editor.value}" />
</h:form>

       </h:body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Anything relevant in the logfile?

Comment: no there is no any error appearing in log

Comment: just :  HTTP Status 404 - /jsf-blank/NewFile.xhtml ,, but when deleting primfaces jar file it will work ! .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832964/primefaces-required-jsf-version), Primefaces 3.5 does not support JSF 2.2, starting from 4.0 it has been supported.
You should consider a switch to the latest Primefaces release.

Read the documentation for more details: [Primefaces User's Guide 3.5](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_3_5.pdf)

Comment: Great, removed my comment