# PrimeFaces: required JSF version

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Which JSF versions are required by PrimeFaces? I am interested in:

- PrimeFaces 3.5
- PrimeFaces 4.0

Comment: Asking here because I could not find a quick answer on http://www.primefaces.org/.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any **JSF 2.x** version is a required dependency for Primefaces.

Additionally, Primefaces 4.0 and above supports the new JSF 2.2 version as well whereas Primefaces 3.5 does not.

So, if you intend to use a JSF 2.2 feature, consider using Primefaces 4.0 since it will support all three i.e. 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2 otherwise you're good to go with version 3.5.

These details are already mentioned in **`Section 2.2 - Dependencies`** of the [Primefaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Answer (score 4):

To use JSF 2.3, Primefaces 6.1 or above is required.

Primefaces 6.1 support JSF 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3

Answer (score 4):

primefaces-9.0        JSF 2.0 - 2.3

primefaces-8.0 JSF 2.0 - 2.3

primefaces-7.0 JSF 2.0 - 2.3

primefaces-6.2 JSF 2.0 - 2.3

**primefaces-6.1 JSF 2.0 - 2.3**

primefaces-6.0 JSF 2.0 - 2.2

primefaces-5.3 JSF 2.0 - 2.2

primefaces-5.2 JSF 2.0 - 2.2

primefaces-5.1 JSF 2.0 - 2.2

**PrimeFaces 4.0 JSF 2.0 - 2.2**

**PrimeFaces 3.5 JSF 2.0 - 2.1**

As you can see the version of Primefaces and compatible JSF version. Its better to go with primeface 4.0 which can be further enhance upto 6.0 without upgrading the JSF (2.0-2.2)

If there is not mandatory then it would be best to go with primeface 6.1 or upper

Answer (score 0):

In addition to these answers, it's important to consider that when using an application server as like payara, wildly or other, the libraries are included. You must not worry about it. While If you use a web server, you must include these libraries according to primefaces version