# Integrating JSF with struts 1.2

Tags: jsf, struts-1

We have old application which is developed in struts 1.2 and now we have developed new application which is completely developed on jsf + primefaces. Can anyone tell me if its possible to integrate both as we are planning to call functionalities of struts application?.

Thanks,
Brijesh

Comment: jsf 1.2 with primefaces? is it even possible? [PrimeFaces: required JSF version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832964/primefaces-required-jsf-version)

Comment: I am using jsf 2.1 and primefaces 3.4 but i am not sure if jsf can talk to struts 1.2 but it can talk to struts 2

Comment: Depends what you mean on 'talk' - they both share the same session state, so you can put common data in there for interstate communication, but if you mean jsf access struts actions/forms then no, and you'd likely want to rebuild them anyway in JSF.